# Small doubts in a proof of the Cantor-Bernstein theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Kolmogorov/Fomin's Introductory Real Analysis, here:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

---

**Questions:**

1. I can see that $A \supset A_2 \supset A_4 \dots$ and $A_1 \supset A_3 \supset A_5 \dots$ but it's not clear to me why $A \supset A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset ...$
2. It's not clear to me why $A-A_1$ is equivalent to $A_2-A_3$, can you expand a little bit more about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A_2 = g(B_1)\subseteq g(B) = A_1$$ for the first one. For the second,
\begin{align}
(g\circ f)(A-A_1) = g(f(A-A_1)) = g(f(A) - f(A_1)) = g(B_1-B_2) = \\
=g(B_1) - g(B_2) = A_2-A_3.
\end{align}

This is because $f$ and $g$ are injections and so they are also injections when restricted to any subset such as $A-A_1.$